# Is there a way to open .et files with 14 04 LTS?

Tags: permissions, default-programs

I have just come over to Ubuntu and I am very pleased with it. However I have a very important file that I backed up from windows and I am unable to open it. It is an a `.et` file created by Kingsoft spreadsheets.

Is there a way to open this file?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, install [Kingsoft](http://wps-community.org/download.html) in Linux. You can open the file in there.

If needed save the file as a txt or csv so you can open it in Libre Office and delete Kingsoft.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to install `WPS Office` in Linux.

Kingsoft Office free vesion, Kingsoft Office paid version, Kingsoft Office 2012, Kingsoft Office 2013, Kingsoft Office for Android, Kingsoft Office for Linux and Kingsoft Office for IOS has been changed in to WPS Office.

`WPS Office Free` is perhaps the most versatile free office suite, which includes free word processor, spreadsheet program and presentation maker. These three programs help you deal with office tasks with ease:

`Writer` - Efficient word processor.

`Presentation` - Multimedia presentations creator.

`Spreadsheets` - Powerful tool for data processing and data analysis.

Although it is a free suite, `WPS Office` comes with many innovative features, including a paragraph adjustment tool, and multiple tabbed feature. It also has Office to PDF converter, automatic spell checking and word count features.